# Problem with deploying Next.js app on Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, docker-compose

I have a VPS Ubuntu 22.04 and I want to build and run a Next.js application inside a Docker container.

It means that I don't want NodeJS installed on Ubuntu, instead node:18-alpine should do all the work.

I'm facing an issue that after running the `docker-compose build` / `docker-compose up -d` commands, the container keeps restarting with the error:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/.next/BUILD_ID'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/app/.next/BUILD_ID'
}
```

There are no `node_modules` and `.next` folders in the `./data/app` directory on Ubuntu (since I want them to be created inside the container at the time of build and launch).

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
  node:
    build:
      context: ./data/app
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./data/app:/app:cached
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm install -g next

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**package.json scripts:**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
},
```

Comment: The `volumes:` block is overwriting the image's entire `/app` directory with what happens to be on the local system, which might be different in your local environment from the deployed system.  Are you checking out your entire source tree on the remote system?  If so, could you use plain Node without Docker; or it not, does deleting the entire `volumes:` block help?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks David! The problem caused by volumes mounting

Answer (score 0):

As [@DavidMaze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) mentioned, the problem is caused by mounting the volumes.

**Description of the cause of the problem:**

From the terms of the question, Ubuntu does not have NodeJS, so the project does not have `node_modules` and `.next` folders.
After running `docker-compose build`, the `node_modules` and `.next` folders are created inside container, but after running `docker-compose up -d`, volumes from `docker-comsope.yml` are mounted, and since the host does not have these folders, they are mounted without them, so the container does not see theirs.

**How to fix the problem:**

You need to add the `node_modules` and `.next` folders as an exception so that they are not deleted in the container after mounting.

```
  node:
    build:
      context: ./data/app
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./data/app:/app
      - /app/node_modules <-- add this
      - /app/.next <-- add this
```

After that, everything will work as it should.

If you still have errors in your container due to the missing `.next` folder, then try this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

If there are errors with this Dockerfile, you need to remove the node container (`docker stop <container_name>` and `docker rm <container_name>`), then run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: This doesn't add an "exception" to the volume mount.  It stores those directories in _anonymous volumes_, which are just like Docker named volumes but they don't have names.  That means that your application will ignore changes to your `package.json` file, even if you rebuild the underlying image.  A better approach would be to delete the `volumes:` block entirely.